# C++: Hide base static member

Tags: c++, class, oop, static, field

In C++, is it possible to have a child class "hide" a base class' static fields and methods? (i.e. A has a field named ABC of type int, B:A and B has a field named ABC of type int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
     public:
    static int a;
};

class B: public A{
     public:
      static  int a; // hide base member

 };

int A::a;
int B::a;
int main(){
    A::a=10;
    B::a=20;

    B k;
    cout << "\n" << B::a << k.a;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it will be hidden (but clients can still access the member of base class if they specify the base class name explicitly, for example `A::a`).

Comment: Or `B::A::a` (which is the same thing)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
class B : private A
{
...
};
```

This will hide everything though, not just statics.

Comment: Missing ending semicolon.  ;D

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to privately inherit?

```
class B : private A {
    // ...
};
```